# SQL: Count() based on column value

Tags: sql, count

I have a table as follows:

```
CallID   | CompanyID  | OutcomeID
----------------------------------
1234     | 3344       | 36
1235     | 3344       | 36
1236     | 3344       | 36
1237     | 3344       | 37
1238     | 3344       | 39
1239     | 6677       | 37
1240     | 6677       | 37
```

I would like to create a SQL script that counts the number of Sales outcomes and the number of all the other attempts (anything <> 36), something like:

```
CompanyID  | SalesCount  | NonSalesCount
------------------------------------------
3344       | 3           | 1
6677       | 0           | 2
```

Is there a way to do a COUNT() that contains a condition like COUNT(CallID WHERE OutcomeID = 36)?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression with your aggregate to get a total based on the `outcomeId` value:

```
select companyId,
  sum(case when outcomeid = 36 then 1 else 0 end) SalesCount,
  sum(case when outcomeid <> 36 then 1 else 0 end) NonSalesCount
from yourtable
group by companyId;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15821)

Comment: @BrianKE: Can `outcomeid` ever be NULL?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
SELECT companyId,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN outcomeid = 36 THEN 1 END) SalesCount,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN outcomeid <> 36 THEN 1 END) NonSalesCount
FROM 
  yourtable
GROUP BY 
  companyId
```

should work -- `COUNT()` counts only not null values.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Count doesn't count NULL values, so you can do this:

```
select
  COUNT('x') as Everything,
  COUNT(case when OutcomeID = 36 then 'x' else NULL end) as Sales,
  COUNT(case when OutcomeID <> 36 then 'x' else NULL end) as Other
from
  YourTable
```

Alternatively, you can use SUM, like bluefeet demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    companyId, SalesCount, TotalCount-SalesCount AS NonSalesCount
FROM
    (
    select
      companyId,
      COUNT(case when outcomeid = 36 then 1 else NULL end) SalesCount,
      COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
    from yourtable
    group by companyId
    ) X;
```

Using this mutually exclusive pattern with `COUNT(*)`

- avoids a (very small) overhead of evaluating a second conditional `COUNT`
- gives correct values if `outcomeid` can be NULL

Using @bluefeet's [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15823) with added NULLs

Answer (score 2):

Knowing `COUNT()` and `SUM()` only count non-null values and the following rule:

```
true or null = true
false or null = null
```

For fiddling around, you can take Taryn's answer and circumvent `CASE` altogether in a super-dirty and error-prone way!

```
select companyId,
  sum(outcomeid = 36 or null) SalesCount,
  sum(outcomeid <> 36 or null) NonSalesCount
from yourtable
group by companyId;
```

Forget to add an `or null` and you'll be counting everything!