# SQL To count values of multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table, with columns like this:

name1,name2,name_thesame,adress1,adress2,adress_thesame,city1,city2,city_thesame

In all columns ending with _thesame, there is a true or false depending if name1 and name2 are the same, same with adress etc etc.

I now need a query that returns a count how many true and false i got for each of the _thesame columns.

Cant wrap my head around how to do this query - any body got some ideas or pointers? Thanks

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The question is not entirely clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194145/sql-count-based-on-column-value is practically the same question

Comment: @Terminus - right, practically same.

Comment: @user5051310 The linked question counts a single column, while this counts multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single property you can do:

```
select name_thesame, count(*) 
from table
group by name_thesame
```

This will give you results like:

```
 true     10
 false    15
```

If you want to have it as a list for multiple columns, you can just union the queries:

```
select 'Name', name_thesame, count(*) 
  from table
  group by name_thesame
union 
select 'Address', adress_thesame, count(*) 
  from table
  group by adress_thesame
```

getting:

```
 Name    true   10
 Name    false  15
 Address true   20
 Address false  5
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that would give me the correct results. However I was hoping for a solution to do it programmaticly, so I dont have to hard code every column name, as there are 100+ where I want the counts to be done. But I will accept the answer and do the hard coding, thanks

Comment: To be honest, 100+ (meaning 300+ field in the table) is a bit of a red flag, design wise :)

Comment: @user2199192, specify a database platform, I'll try to draft a script that will write the query for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is another option:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN name_thesame = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nametrue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN name_thesame = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as namefalse,
       SUM(CASE WHEN adress_thesame = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as adresstrue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN adress_thesame = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as adressfalse,
       SUM(CASE WHEN city_thesame = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as citytrue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN city_thesame = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cityfalse
FROM yourTable
```

You can tweak it to deal with `NULL`s as well if relevant:

```
...
CASE WHEN name_thesame = false OR name_thesame IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
...
```

or either `NVL()`, `ISNULL()`, `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`, depending on the DBMS you're using (syntax is always the same):

```
...
CASE WHEN COALESCE(name_thesame, false) = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
...
```

Result:

```
nametrue | namefalse | adresstrue | adressfalse | citytrue | cityfalse
       5 |         7 |          2 |           1 |       10 |         8
```

Comment: If he doesn't have `NULL` can he just subtract # of true from the total # of rows to get # of false?

Comment: Of course it can be done, but it wouldn't make the query shorter or more performant (something like `COUNT(*) - SUM(CASE WHEN name_thesame = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`). Unless I miss something obvious ?

Comment: Could put it in the application but I thinking about it, no idea if that's in any way better.